# Artifact not found in JCenter after name change

Tags: bintray, jcenter

I recently updated the name and artifact name of some of my packages in JCenter ([example](https://bintray.com/eygraber/maven/kodein-di-android-components)) and I updated the coordinates in Gradle accordingly. However, the new artifacts are not found no matter what I do.

I checked JCenter directly, and they appear to be there. Is there something that I need to do to get it to work again?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that when you submit a JCenter inclusion request for a particular package, all the artifactIDs present under the groupID will be included in the JCenter. If you add additional artifactIDs under the already included groupID , those artifactIDs will not be mirrored in JCenter because JCenter hosts **Single path for a single package**.

In your case for the package "kodein-di-android-components" there are two artifactIDs under the groupID "com/eygraber"
1. kodein-android-components
2. kodein-di-android-components

Only the First artifactID "kodein-android-components" is included in JCenter,
In order to add the second artifactID "kodein-di-android-components" create a new 
Bintray package for the artifactID "kodein-di-android-components" and include all the files under the path *GroupID+ artifactID* i.e *com/eygraber/kodein-di-android-components* so that the package will be hosted in JCenter under the path
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/eygraber

[image]

Comment: Is there documentation for this anywhere? If this is the case, then they shouldn't allow you to do this without warning you about it.